# In CakePHP, is there a better way to select the users name?

Tags: cakephp

I currently have a `users` table and a `posts` table. My posts table has a field for `user_id`, however, I am not sure how I would grab the users `name` field which is in the `users` table. I was thinking of using the models `afterFind()` method and then using SQL to select the data, but there has to be a better way than this. Also, on my view action, I am using the `read()` function to grab a single post. Would the models `afterFind()` kick in after it runs `read()`? If not, is there an equivalent such as `afterRead()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an association of Post belongsTo User, and every regular find/read operation that has a sufficiently high `recursive` value will automatically fetch the user with each post.

```
$post = $this->Post->find(...);
echo $post['User']['name'];
```

Comment: I'd use `echo h($post['User']['name'])` - for security reasons! always escape your output.

Comment: Interesting, I have never heard of output escaping. I have only heard of input escaping, but I guess it makes sense. However, if I had tight restrictions on my input then I wouldn't need to escape for output right?

Comment: @Doug Always escape all user-supplied values, period. Unless you're reformatting it into something guaranteed harmless, like `(int)$val` or `date('Y-m-d', $date)`.

Comment: Should it be escaped in the model or view? Also, what if I am pulling multiple things from the database? Does that mean I have to escape everything? I can just escape `h($post)` instead of the more specific right?

Comment: @Doug Escape on output. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512873/is-it-better-to-escape-encode-the-user-input-before-storing-it-to-database-or-to/. And yes, you'll have to escape every individual value, at least by looping over them. Security doesn't come for free.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go like below :

```
$this->Cake->findById(7);   Cake.id = 7
```

here , you can you use your **user_id** instead of 7 like..

[Find BY CAKE PHP](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1026/findBy)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Post->bindModel(array('belongsTo'=>'User'));
$post = $this->Post->findById($post_id);
$userName = $post['User']['name'];
```

Here are errors, I've typed it in eclipse (: